How is the coveo facet configured?
We are using Sitecore 10.1 and Coveo for Sitecore 5, we use it on the general site search page, we have a facet By Content Type as shown in the following screenshot, if I select Videos I got one result, but if I select All Results that video is not shown up.
I could not find the code that reacts to the facet click. Can anyone help me understand how Coveo facets work? and how it is configured?



Coveo facet options are being pulled dynamically from a selected data source field, read more here.
There is no "ALL" option out-of-the-box and I assume that the very first "All Results" option has been added by your custom code. Technically when you select the "All Results" option you should clear your Content Type facet to its initial state with no other options selected.
As a next step I would recommend to review your custom code and find out how it interacts with the Coveo events and queries. Specifically look for deferredQuerySucces event that is being triggered when a Query gets executed successfully and a Facet component is ready to be rendered.
Once you know your specific event flow it will be clear where to make some code corrections to your query expression.
